# How to reference the value of another cell as a condition in a for loop? (R)

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I want to set a condition such that if the co-ordinates of a cell in a dataframe are [i,j] where j=i+1, then the value of the cell should equal 1. For example, in the dataframe (df) below with 5 columns and 4 rows:

```
A 0 0 0 0
B 0 0 0 0
C 0 0 0 0 
D 0 0 0 0
```

It should end up looking like:

```
A 1 0 0 0
B 0 1 0 0
C 0 0 1 0 
D 0 0 0 1
```

I tried the following:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
for(j in 1:ncol(df)){
if(j==i+1){
df[i,j] == 1
}}}
```

This code doesn't change anything in the df. I think the reason it doesn't work is because it references the actual values in  [i,j] as opposed to their 'co-ordinates' in the dataframe?

I then tried:

```
for(i in df[nrow(df)]){
for(j in df[ncol(df)]){
if (j==i+1){
df[i,j]==1
}}}
```

and get this:

> Warning message:
>   In if (j == i + 1) { :
>   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

I will be scaling up the solution to a bigger dataframe (214x215) so I thought a loop might be the best way to do it. Any advice/comments on errors in my code or better ways to do this would be much appreciated! Please let me know if anything needs clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Try `df[i,j]=1` or `df[i,j] <- 1` in your for loop `==` is the logical operator

Comment: Don't use a loop. Try `diag(df) <- 1` instead, possibly after subsetting `df`, like in `diag(df[,-1]) <- 1`

Comment: thanks @NicE - I needed to brush up on operators!

Comment: also - 'diag' was exactly what I needed for now. @RHertel - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are two methods for assigning without using a loop. Both use logical indexing and assume that the dataframe is named `dat` (which is preferred since `df` is a function name, density function of the F-distribution):

```
dat[ cbind(1:4, 1+1:4) ] <- 1 # or use `nrow` and `length` as the second args to ":"
dat[ row(dat) == col(dat) -1] <- 1
```

Both dataframes and matrices have a `col` and `row` function that returns the index "in place":

```
> col(dat)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5
[4,]    1    2    3    4    5
```